# disable button via js

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I need to disable button in case the text input value length is less than 3.

I was trying to use js but the button is not disabled its just changing is color

```
 <p:autoComplete id="ac"
                    value="#{bean.selectedNetCode}" 
                    completeMethod="#{bean.complete}"
                    maxlength="3"
                    size="3"
                    maxResults="10"
                    onkeyup="checkLength(this.value)">
        <p:ajax event="itemSelect" update="genButton" listener="#{bean.handleNetCodeChange}"/>
    </p:autoComplete> 



 function checkLength(value){
      if(value.length <= 2){
      document.getElementById("genButton").disabled = true;
 }
```

Any idea why ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define the attribute `widgetVar` of `p:commandButton`, and that will give you access to the component via javascript.

Then, you have some methods at your disposal. [From PrimeFaces 3.4 Documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html):

> - disable(): Disables button
> - enable(): Enables button

---

Example:

```
<p:autoComplete onkeyup="checkLength(this.value)">/>
<p:commandButton widgetVar="myButton" />

function checkLength(value){
     if(value.length <= 2)
         myButton.disable();
}
```

---

**UPDATE 07/2021**:

As pointed by dian jin in the comments, when using PimeFaces 4.0 to 5.0 you will need to call `PF('myButton').disable();` to reference widgetVar properly.

Comment: Note to anyone that stumbles upon this later using PimeFaces 4.0 to 5.0, if you're receiving the `Uncaught ReferenceError`, based on the context above, you will need to call `PF('myButton').disable();` to reference widgetVar properly

https://code.google.com/archive/p/primefaces/wikis/MigrationGuide.wiki